BigQuery Load Job doesn't respect default value set in schema
When creating the table I set
ingress_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_DATETIME
When looking at my schema in BigQuery I can see it worked:

I have a .json file in my bucket that has all the same columns as the table, expect for the ingress_at. I'm now trying to append the data in this file to the existing table, the data loads fine, but I keep ending up with NULL values all throughout the ingress_at table. Why is it not populated with the ingress date time as specified?
I've tried:

setting CURRENT_DATETIME() instead of CURRENT_DATETIME in the schema at table creation => no change

making ingress_at a REQUIRED field => load job fails because there's no such column in import file

setting auto detect TRUE when configuring the load job => errors because the file doesn't have headers and the ingress_at column doesn't exist

defining a schema for the load job => loads fine, but ingress_at column is entirely populated with NULL values



In Google BigQuery, default values specified in the table schema are not applied during load jobs. However, default values are used when inserting data via SQL INSERT statements. When you load data into BigQuery, if a column is missing in the source data, it will be populated with NULL values, regardless of the default value specified in the table schema.
Workaround 1:

Create a Staging Table.
Load your JSON data into a staging table that has the same schema as your original table, but without the ingress_at column.

Insert Data with Default Value: Use an SQL INSERT statement to insert data from the staging table into the target table, setting ingress_at to CURRENT_DATETIME().
Here is an example code:


INSERT INTO your_target_table (column1, column2, ..., ingress_at)
SELECT column1, column2, ..., CURRENT_DATETIME()
FROM your_staging_table;
Workaroud 2:
If you have a more complex ETL pipeline, consider using Google Cloud Dataflow to transform the data as it is being loaded. Dataflow allows you to process the data and add the CURRENT_DATETIME() to the ingress_at field before loading it into BigQuery like below:
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from datetime import datetime

class AddIngressAt(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        element['ingress_at'] = datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
        yield element

def run():
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        (p
         | 'ReadFromGCS' >> beam.io.ReadFromText('gs://your-bucket/your-file.json')
         | 'ParseJson' >> beam.Map(json.loads)
         | 'AddIngressAt' >> beam.ParDo(AddIngressAt())
         | 'WriteToBigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
             'your-project:your_dataset.your_table',
             schema='column1:STRING, column2:STRING, ..., ingress_at:TIMESTAMP',
             write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
         )
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()


in option 1, why do I have to set the value as CURRENT_DATETIME() when using the INSERT statement, shouldn't it at least then use the default value? What is the point of the default value setting at all, it seems like when writing data to a table would be the moment for this to be useful, but it can't even be used?

You can set it whatever you want - not only current date time, the point is, it should be done with SQL statement. It is probably being done this way to accelerate operations via ignoring default values.
